# Time-of-day range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

I want to know if a time belongs to an *schedule* or another.

In my case is for calculate if the *time* is in *night schedule* or *normal schedule*.

I have arrived to this solution:

```
NIGHT = ["21:00", "06:00"]
def night?( date )
  date_str = date.strftime( "%H:%M" )
  date_str > NIGHT[0] || date_str < NIGHT[1]
end
```

But I think is not very elegant and also only works for this concrete case and not every *time range*.

(I've found several similar question is *SO* but all of them make reference to *Date* ranges no *Time* ranges)

### Updated

Solution has to work for random time ranges not only for this concrete one. Let's say:

```
"05:00"-"10:00"
"23:00"-"01:00"
"01:00"-"01:10"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually more or less how I would do it, except maybe a bit more concise:

```
def night?( date )
    !("06:00"..."21:00").include?(date.strftime("%H:%M"))
end
```

or, if your schedule boundaries can remain on the hour:

```
def night?(date)
    !((6...21).include? date.hour)
end
```

Note the `...` - that means, basically, "day time is hour 6 to hour 21 but *not including* hour 21".

edit: here is a generic (and sadly much less pithy) solution:

```
class TimeRange
    private

    def coerce(time)
        time.is_a? String and return time
        return time.strftime("%H:%M")
    end

    public

    def initialize(start,finish)
        @start = coerce(start)
        @finish = coerce(finish)
    end

    def include?(time)
        time = coerce(time)
        @start < @finish and return (@start..@finish).include?(time)
        return !(@finish..@start).include?(time)
    end
end
```

You can use it almost like a normal Range:

```
irb(main):013:0> TimeRange.new("02:00","01:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,02,30))
=> true
irb(main):014:0> TimeRange.new("02:00","01:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,01,30))
=> false
irb(main):015:0> TimeRange.new("01:00","02:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,01,30))
=> true
irb(main):016:0> TimeRange.new("01:00","02:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,02,30))
=> false
```

Note, the above class is ignorant about time zones.

Comment: I like second version. I think that is the best solution, because we don't care about minutes, just hours.

Comment: I'm looking for a general range solution not only one special case. **First version only works** only works for ranges those don't cross _24:00_. Same that my solution only works for ranges those cross _24:00_. What about _23:00...01:00_ without using the opposite range?. **Second version is not correct** for _06:10_ which is not night.

Comment: Ok, please amend your question.

Comment: @Michael I have updated it with examples. Maybe my concrete example brought confusion, I tried to explain my concern with the sentence _" only works for this concrete case and not every time range"_.

Comment: Watch out for time zone issues. I also think funny things may happen here across daylight saving transitions.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3.2 it has added Time.all_day and similars as a way of generating date ranges. I think you must see how it works. It may be useful.

Comment: Could you please rephrase this so it answers the question?