# How to define time intervals in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following task: I need to store in db (PostgreSQL) some time intervals; for example, 1 PM - 2 PM in order to I can test if some time exists in some interval. How should I do it properly? May be there is some gem for it? Thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the columns as @Santosh said and then if you need to check something against a time range you can use this useful class:

[Time-of-day range in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045396/time-of-day-range-in-ruby)

```
class TimeRange
    private

    def coerce(time)
        time.is_a? String and return time
        return time.strftime("%H:%M")
    end

    public

    def initialize(start,finish)
        @start = coerce(start)
        @finish = coerce(finish)
    end

    def include?(time)
        time = coerce(time)
        @start < @finish and return (@start..@finish).include?(time)
        return !(@finish..@start).include?(time)
    end
end
```

which can be used this way:

```
irb(main):013:0> TimeRange.new("02:00","01:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,02,30))
=> true
irb(main):014:0> TimeRange.new("02:00","01:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,01,30))
=> false
irb(main):015:0> TimeRange.new("01:00","02:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,01,30))
=> true
irb(main):016:0> TimeRange.new("01:00","02:00").include?(Time.mktime(2010,04,01,02,30))
=> false
```